# Can you use `php artisan serve` with nginx like with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, laravel, nginx

The question above is for pure education, not for use in real world.

When reading on how to deploy a nodejs app on a VPS, I have found out, that nginx is forwarding all requests to a localhost port, which is served by node a nodejs app.

here is a nodejs config in digitalocean tutorial:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

I was wondering is the same possible with nginx and Laravel's `php artisan serve`? (for sure this will also need a process manager that will restart the app in case it fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible, and somebody asked about it: [How to use "php artisan serve" in a remote server - DigitalOcean](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/how-to-access-localhost8000-in-a-remote-server-when-using-php-artisan-serve-digitalocean). You can do a similar thing.

`artisan serve` is a wrapper for PHP’s built-in server, and while this is fine for pure educational reasons, **“It is not intended to be a full-featured web server. It should not be used on a public network.”** See [Built-in web server](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) for more.